# Problem in solving non-linear differential equation having Gaussian function

Tags: plotting, differential-equations, numerical-integration

```
   we = 30*10^-6; P0 = 3; \[Gamma] = 0.070; g = 10; \[Rho] = 1000; c = 
   3*10^8;
   \[Kappa][r_] := (z''[r] + z'[r]/r); \[CapitalPi][r_] := (4 P0)/(
    Pi*we^2*c) Exp[-((2*r^2)/we^2)];
   Solsol = NDSolve[{-\[Gamma]*\[Kappa][r] + \[Rho]*g*z[r] - \[CapitalPi][
   r] == 0, z[50*we] == 0, z'[0] == 0}, z[r], {r, 0, 10 we}]
   g = Plot[Evaluate[{z[r], z'[r], z''[r]} /. sol], {r, 0, 10 we}, 
    PlotStyle -> Automatic]
```

Comment: You have a differential equation, therefore you need NDSolve instead of NSolve. Further, Infinity is not a number  and can not be used as function argument.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have singularity at `r=0` due to `(z''[r] + z'[r]/r)` so can't start at zero. Try `$MachineEpsilon`

```
ClearAll["Global`*"]
we = 30*10^-6;
P0 = 3;
γ = 0.070;
g = 10;
ρ = 1000;
c = 3*10^8;
ode0 = (z''[r] + z'[r]/r)
h = (4 P0)/(Pi*we^2*c) Exp[-((2*r^2)/we^2)];
ode = -γ*ode0 + ρ*g*z[r] - h == 0
ic = {z[50*we] == 0, z'[$MachineEpsilon] == 0};
sol = NDSolve[{ode, ic}, z[r], {r, $MachineEpsilon, 10 we}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

```
g = Plot[Evaluate[{z[r], z'[r], z''[r]} /. sol], {r, $MachineEpsilon, 10 we}, 
  PlotStyle -> Automatic]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

**Update**

To plot the derivatives, you can do this. You can actually have `NDSolve` solve for these.

```
sol = NDSolve[{ode, ic}, {z, z', z''}, {r, $MachineEpsilon, 10 we}]
```

Then do

```
g = Plot[
  Evaluate[{z[r], z'[r], z''[r]} /. sol], {r, $MachineEpsilon, 10 we}, 
  PlotStyle -> Automatic, PlotRange -> All]
```

Now 3 curves show up. But the scales are so different, hard to see them all on same plot. You can plot each on separate plots? Something like

```
opt = {PlotRange -> All, ImageSize -> 300, GridLines -> Automatic, 
   GridLinesStyle -> LightGray, PlotStyle -> Red};
p1 = Plot[Evaluate[z[r] /. sol], {r, $MachineEpsilon, 10 we}, 
   Evaluate@opt, PlotLabel -> "z(r)"];
p2 = Plot[Evaluate[z'[r] /. sol], {r, $MachineEpsilon, 10 we}, 
   Evaluate@opt, PlotLabel -> "z'(r)"];
p3 = Plot[Evaluate[z''[r] /. sol], {r, $MachineEpsilon, 10 we}, 
   Evaluate@opt, PlotLabel -> "z''(r)"];
Column[{p1, p2, p3}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

> I am trying to vary [Gamma] using sol = ParametricNDSolve[{ode, ic},
> z, {r, $MachineEpsilon, 200 we}, {[Gamma]}] then I want to calculate
> A0 = -[Gamma*a^2*( (z''[[Gamma]][r] - z'[[Gamma]][r]/r for two
> differnt value of [Gamma] ) 0.030 and 0.070.

You can use `ParametricNDSolve`

```
ClearAll["Global`*"]
we = 30*10^-6;
P0 = 3;
g = 10;
ρ = 1000;
c = 3*10^8;
ode0 = (z''[r] + z'[r]/r)
h = (4 P0)/(Pi*we^2*c) Exp[-((2*r^2)/we^2)];
ode = -γ*ode0 + ρ*g*z[r] - h == 0
ic = {z[50*we] == 0, z'[$MachineEpsilon] == 0};
sol=ParametricNDSolve[{ode,ic},z,{r,$MachineEpsilon,10 we},γ]

z1 = z[0.030] /. sol;
z2 = z[0.070] /. sol;
Plot[{z1[r], z2[r]}, {r, $MachineEpsilon, 10 we}, 
 PlotLegends -> {"0.03", "0.07"}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

```
γ = 0.030;
z1 = z[γ] /. sol
a = 1;
A0 = -γ*a^2*(z1''[r] - z1'[r]/r)

γ = 0.070;
z2 = z[γ] /. sol
A0 = -γ*a^2*(z2''[r] - z2'[r]/r)
```

Comment: Thanks, but it it showing only z(r) its derivatives z'(r) z''(r) not showing.

Comment: thanks! derivative z''(r) near 0 is not so clear, Please also try to plot (z''(r)+z'(r)/r)/2 which is the mean curvature.

Comment: Please suggest how to use ParametricNDSolve so that I can vary "we" for two different values.

Comment: @GopalVerma I do not think you can use the location of initial conditions as a parameter.  But why not simply make a function and pass it `we` value, and solve the same equation each time you want to change `we` by making a call to this function with different `we`? This is much simpler solution and you do not have to deal with complexity of ParametricNDSolve.

Comment: Thanks, I got it.

Comment: I am trying to vary \[Gamma] using sol = ParametricNDSolve[{ode, ic}, 
  z, {r, $MachineEpsilon, 200 we}, {\[Gamma]}] then I want to calculate A0 = -\[Gamma*a^2*( (z''[\[Gamma]][r] - z'[\[Gamma]][r]/r for two differnt value of \[Gamma] ) 0.030 and 0.070. Please suggest how to do it.

Comment: @GopalVerma fyi, updated

Comment: The code works for z1[r] and z2[r] but I am not able to generate a plot of A0.